# Concatenation of 2 strings failing because of incompatible operands error returned by PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, string-concatenation

I'm trying to run the following code :

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "https://www.emploi-public.ma/ar/index.asp?p="
number_of_jobs = 0
houceima = u"الحسيمة"
print type(houceima)
for i in range(1,3):
    page_link = link+str(i)
    print page_link
    emp_pub = requests.get(page_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(emp_pub.content,"lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        if houceima in link :
            print link
```

But I'm getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_houceima", line 9, in <module>
    page_link = link+str(i)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'
```

I'm using PyCharm. I stated my IDE because the same concatenation `page_link = link+str(i)` executed well in IDLE.
What could be the problem here ?

Comment: You replaced the string (`link = "http://..."`) in the `for` loop further on (`for link in soup.find_all(...):`. Don't mask variables like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re-used `link` in your code:

```
link = "https://www.emploi-public.ma/ar/index.asp?p="
```

and

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
```

The latter use *replaces* the first `link` reference, so it is no longer a string object but a `Tag` object.

Don't mask variables like that, rename one or the other. Perhaps the first use could be named `base_url`?